# c++ pointer type and call by reference

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference

I have a problem with pointer type when writing my program.
The code looks like follows:

```
datatype B;
int func(datatype* A){
 A=&B;
};
int main(int argc,char** argv){
 dataType* mainA=new dataType;
 func(mainA);
}
```

What I want is after excuting `func(mainA)`. `mainA` is point to B. I know my code is wrong, after that, mainA did not change. I thought this should like something called call by reference. Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the parameter a reference to pointer. Lastly, a pointer is also an object and can be modified through references.

```
int func(datatype*& A)
{
    A = &B;
}
```

However, I would prefer to return the result and assign it:

```
datatype* func()
{
    return &B;
}

// […]

dataType* mainA = func();
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to declare the `A` parameter as a reference to a pointer:

```
int func(datatype *&A){
```

Now the pointer itself will be passed by reference so `func()` will be allowed to change `mainA` if you pass it in.